# RN 0.21.0 "Debug JS" doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I upgrade RN to 0.21.0 with command `npm install --save react-native@0.21`.

Then, "Debug JS" doesn't work , and throws exception "Unable to connect with remote debugger", But RN 0.20.0 is OK.

`npm: 2.14.15`

`node: v5.3.0`

`watchman: 4.4.0`

`flow: 0.22.1`

`React Developer Tools: 0.14.8`

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWYGi.png)

Answer (score 2):

Have u upgraded your gradle files? If you are testing on Android than check your build.gradle if it the following line exists:

```
compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.21.+"
```

If it is still set to ..0.20.+ than you need to do a react-native upgrade, but save your current imports etc in build.gradle (app folder), settings.gradle and MainActivity imports and put them back after upgrade. If this doesn´t work than:

1. Remove node_module folder
2. Run watchman watch-del-all
3. Run npm install
4. Than start packager with react-native start --reset-cache

Goog Luck!

Comment: It works for me, even without "Run watchman watch-del-all"
Thanks!